# FluentValidator, как валидировать поле при условии, что другое поле уже прошло проверку?

Tags: c#, fluent-validator

Допустим, что есть такая модель:

```
class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
}
```

Как можно провалидировать св-во `Guid`, если `Id`, например, есть в базе данных?

Что я пробовал и что получилось - проверка `Id` в базе, но как исходя из ответа на валидацию `Id` сделать валидацию для `Guid`? Т.е. если `Id` не прошел валидацию, то `Guid` не стоит валидировать вообще.

```
class TestValidator : AbstractValidator<Test>
{
    public TestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).MustAsync(CheckIdInDb);
    }

    private Task<bool> CheckIdInDb(int arg1, CancellationToken arg2)
    {
        //...check in db

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

`When` не сработает, там простой предикат, да и дважды ходить в базу не хотелось бы.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ случайно нашелся [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60868572/fluent-validator-for-when-another-property-is-true)
Нужно использовать DependentRules, куда и положить проверку поля `Guid`.

```
RuleFor(x => x.Id).MustAsync(CheckIdInDb).DependentRules(() => RuleFor(x => x.Guid).NotEmpty());
```